# PMD Avoid using a branching statement as the last in a loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pmd

I'm using the following code to iterate through table cells and gettext of a link.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//table[@id='classificationResults']/tbody/tr/td[3]/a")
private List<WebElement> nameColumnRows;

  public String getNameLinkText() {
         for (WebElement element: nameColumnRows) {
             return element.getText();
         }
       return "could not find name links";
   }
```

This works fine for me. However the PMD giving the following error. 
**Avoid using a branching statement as the last in a loop.**

My question is whether I should ignore the warning or use some other approach to when iterating through table rows/cells, columns.

Thanks,

Comment: Your current implementation will _only_ return `nameColumnRows.get(0).getText()` or `"could not find name links"`.  Is this intended?

Comment: Hi @LouisWasserman Thanks for your response. No it iterates through all the rows in the table and returns the link value. tested it with a println..

Comment: Please provide your test code, because I don't believe it.  `return` exits the method _immediately_, returning the value passed to it.

Comment: I get the value from the above method and check whether it's == to the value i need using

Comment: What do you _expect_ to be returned?  This method only returns one `String`, and it's just the first one from `nameColumnRows`.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete comment above. I get the value from the above method and verify whether it displays the required value using the below method stored in Cucumber-StepDefinition class                                  public void verifyMarkingTypeColumnValue(String value) {  
assertThat(getMarkingTypeColumnVal‌​ues(), equalTo(value); 

}